Query child documents based off field that is only present in parent?
In my MongoDB collection I have a documents that follow a parent-child structure.
Each parent doc typically has 4 fields, with the children having 3 (no group field).
parent:
{
_id: doc_123
parent_id: 123
active: true
group: A
}

children
{
id: doc_123_1
parent_id: 123
active: true
}

{
id: doc_123_2
parent_id: 123
active: true
}

I want to write a BSON query / aggregation if needed for my Java Spring project that will return all the docs that match the following fields provided by user:

active field - this will be true or false
group field - e.g "A"

My difficulty is that each child document is assumed to have the same value as the parent for the group field, but it is not actually in the document.
How can I write a query that will match all the parent and child documents for a certain group?
All documents are in the one collection, there are no separate collections for parent and child docs.

Join to parents adding a condition of group on the join:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // self-join on child.parent_id -> parent.parent_id
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "parent_id",
      foreignField: "parent_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "group": "$$group" // pass "A" as "group" parameter to the query
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "parent"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      active: $$active, // pass true or false as "active" parameter to the query
      group: {
        $exists: false // exclude parents which join to themselves
      }
    }
  }
])

See live demo.
Define this query as a native query in a spring boot Repository and pass it the two named parameters (named "group" and "active").

Can you provide code that does not use spring boot repository? Ideally returning the filters as a List

@java12399900 By awarding the bounty so early we'll never know what contributions it would have attracted.

Aggregation steps:

Search by the group and active true/false based on the user-provided values.

note that only parent records have the group, it's missing/null for children
so this stage returns only the matching parents


Use the parent_id to self-lookup into the same collection and match on parent_id

For whatever reason, the parent_id is identical for children and the parent.
Relying on the id pattern for documents to identify parents & children is a really bad idea: doc_123 for parents and doc_123_1, doc_123_2 for children will be very non-performant for actual search/match/lookups.
Is the id in children called id or _id?  But it doesn't affect the pipeline here.


Exclude the parent record if you want only child records. See the comment for that stage.

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      // set this to a variable for true/false search
      active: true,
      // set this to a variable for group search
      // only "parents" have the group
      group: "A"
    }
  },
  {
    // self-lookup into the same collection, matching on parent_id
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "parent_id",
      foreignField: "parent_id",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$children" },
  { $replaceWith: "$children" },
  {
    // exclude the parents
    // IF YOU WANT PARENTS ALSO THEN REMOVE THIS STAGE
    $match: {
      group: { $exists: false }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thanks @aneroid, I am having difficulty writing this as an aggregate query in java - can you please provide an example in java? everything I try ends up with the children being embedded in the parent objects in the response.

You'll need to convert that aggregation pipeline in JS to whichever library you're using in Java, like this. There are some Spring Boot answers on StackOverflow as well. Some answers just convert that to a string.

I have created a Spring Service that use mongoTemplate and return a List<Bson> as asked
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DocumentService
{
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Bson> getAggregatedDocuments(boolean active, String group, boolean excludeParent)
    {
        List<AggregationOperation> stages = new ArrayList<>();
        stages.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("active").is(active).and("group").is(group)));
        stages.add(Aggregation.lookup("collection", "parent_id", "parent_id", "children"));
        stages.add(Aggregation.unwind("$children"));
        stages.add(Aggregation.replaceRoot("$children"));

        if (excludeParent)
        {
            stages.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("group").exists(false)));
        }

        return mongoTemplate
            .aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(stages), "collection", Bson.class)
            .getMappedResults();
    }
}

Using flapdoodle I can easily test your use case:
@Test
public void getAggregatedDocumentsTest()
{
    DocumentEntity parent = createDocumentEntity("doc_123", 123, true, "A");
    DocumentEntity child1 = createDocumentEntity("doc_123_1", 123, true, null);
    DocumentEntity child2 = createDocumentEntity("doc_123_2", 123, true, null);

    documentRepository.saveAll(List.of(parent, child1, child2));
    System.out.println("All docs = " + documentRepository.findAll());

    var resultWithoutParent = documentService.getAggregatedDocuments(true, "A", true);
    System.out.println("Result without parent = " + resultWithoutParent);

    var resultWithParent = documentService.getAggregatedDocuments(true, "A", false);
    System.out.println("Result with parent = " + resultWithParent);
}

private static DocumentEntity createDocumentEntity(String id, Integer parentId, boolean active, String group)
{
    DocumentEntity documentEntity = new DocumentEntity();
    documentEntity.setId(id);
    documentEntity.setParent_id(parentId);
    documentEntity.setActive(active);
    documentEntity.setGroup(group);

    return documentEntity;
}

And here is the result:

All docs = [DocumentEntity(id=doc_123, parent_id=123, active=true, group=A), DocumentEntity(id=doc_123_1, parent_id=123, active=true, group=null), DocumentEntity(id=doc_123_2, parent_id=123, active=true, group=null)]


Result without parent = [Document{{_id=doc_123_1, parent_id=123, active=true, _class=com.example.demomongo.DocumentEntity}}, Document{{_id=doc_123_2, parent_id=123, active=true, _class=com.example.demomongo.DocumentEntity}}]


Result with parent = [Document{{_id=doc_123, parent_id=123, active=true, group=A, _class=com.example.demomongo.DocumentEntity}}, Document{{_id=doc_123_1, parent_id=123, active=true, _class=com.example.demomongo.DocumentEntity}}, Document{{_id=doc_123_2, parent_id=123, active=true, _class=com.example.demomongo.DocumentEntity}}]

I've created a github repository with the complete project sample here


I want to write a BSON query / aggregation if needed for my Java Spring project that will return all the docs ...

The following Java code returns the output as List<Bson>. This uses the MongoDB Java native driver code to build the aggregation pipeline and run it. This is using Spring Data MongoDB MongoTemplate (Spring Boot version 3.2).
private void runAggregation() {

    MongoOperations ops = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test"); // "test" is the database name
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = ops.getCollection("test"); // "test" is collection name

    List<Bson> pipeline =
            Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",
                            new Document("active", true)
                                    .append("group", "A")),
                    new Document("$lookup",
                            new Document("from", "test")
                                    .append("localField", "parent_id")
                                    .append("foreignField", "parent_id")
                                    .append("as", "children")),
                    new Document("$unwind", "$children"),
                    new Document("$replaceWith", "$children"),
                    new Document("$match",
                            new Document("group",
                                    new Document("$exists", false))));

    List<Bson> result = new ArrayList<>();

    coll.aggregate(pipeline).into(result);

    for (Bson doc : result) {
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}

